# Unable to import mongodump with mongorestore command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to import mongo database from dump.Have a folder named  **iat** which contains all the bson and json files to be imported. Example content of the folder is as below:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 rahul  staff       73 Sep 12 03:42 BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.discovery.bson.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rahul  staff      229 Sep 12 03:42 BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.discovery.metadata.json.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rahul  staff       76 Sep 12 03:42 BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.provisioning.bson.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rahul  staff      234 Sep 12 03:42 BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.provisioning.metadata.json.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rahul  staff       73 Sep 12 03:42 BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.15.discovery.bson.gz
```

Trying to use the command to import dbdump :

```
mongorestore --db dbName iat/
```

Getting the below errors :

```
2015-09-14T12:31:54.641+0530    building a list of collections to restore from iat/ dir
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.discovery.bson.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.discovery.metadata.json.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.provisioning.bson.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.10.provisioning.metadata.json.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.15.discovery.bson.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.15.discovery.metadata.json.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.15.provisioning.bson.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.15.provisioning.metadata.json.gz", skipping...
2015-09-14T12:31:54.645+0530    don't know what to do with file "iat/BaseBundle:Includes1Guest,1Content.16.discovery.bson.gz", skipping...
```

Comment: Yes thanks , i had to decompress the internal files as well by running this inside my folder "gzip -d *.gz"

Comment: Feel free to (properly) answer your own question and accept it. You might want to read [How Do I Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) first.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to decompress, simply use `--gzip` in the command

Comment: using --gzip option actually makes sense, rather than adding another step to decompress it 1st and then running mongorestore. 
worked like a charm.. thanks & kudos.